# Twitter Search (atom), date ranges

Tags: twitter, rss, atom-feed

I have a Twitter feed I'm using for a site, and in theory it should work perfectly, but for some reason

[http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:@goinnative&rpp=10](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3a@goinnative&rpp=10)

only loads 3 tweets (appears to be tweets from the past week) instead of the 10 most recent tweets. Is there some way to use the same feed to call a longer date range?

Comment: your query returns the last three tweets of the searched user 'goinnative'. I don't see any problem here. Twitter search only returns tweets posted in the last week. You can not retrieve the tweets posted earlier than last week.

Comment: Well it works, but if the user hasn't tweeted in the last week the feed is empty and the website I'm fetching it for has an empty marquee. 

So I was asking if there's a way to extend the week limit.

Comment: Currently there isn't any way to do it through twitter api. If it is a must for you, then you can check datasift which is a twitter partnet who share data upto 2 years. http://datasift.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, used this feed instead.

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=goinnative